# CSS3 Border Radius property doesn't work in localhost?

Tags: css

I'm having a very strange problem with css3 border radius property. My following CSS and html works fine with IE9 if i double click the file and open with the IE9 , however if the border property does not work in IE if i open the file through LOCALHOST (xampp insatlled on windows 7). The same file works fine on localhost with other browsers. How can i fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import "circle.css";</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="exampleborderradiusf">F</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.exampleborderradiusf {
    float:left;
    background-color: #464646;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;    
    -moz-border-radius: 35px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE9 is, of course, still in beta, so will have bugs and incomplete features. Its possible you may have stumbled on one of them.

I can't think of too many reasons why a CSS style would stop working while others in the same CSS file continue to work.

Have you checked that IE is still in IE9 mode, and not in IE8-compat mode or something like that. I can see that this sort of thing may change depending on the zone - I've seen similar things happen in IE8 where there's an obscure config setting that can make it switch over to IE7-compat mode when browsing within a local intranet.

Comment: It may sound weird but it has to do something with the localhost+IE9 only, as the same code hosted on the other server on internet works fine with IE9.

Comment: @user547969 - yes, that's why I thought the compat mode thing might be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what you said. For some reason, the browser was set to be in IE 8 mode. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Is your local server delivering the style sheet with the correct MIME-type (`text/css`)?

Comment: hmm.. how can i check that? the other CSS properties work fine on localhost, but only border-radius is having problem, and that too only with IE. All other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari etc.) work fine.

Answer (score 1):

ackkk - i just discovered the same wierdness - exact same page coming from my public server renders fine - coming from localhost - no border-radius

and then
hit F12 on your page and you may discover that for some unhinged reason your localhost file is displaying in IE7 mode
so i stuck this on my page:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9000"
```

it worked
need to research some more but i think you can monkey with IIS to get this automated
this stupid problem was not a good way to spend friday night

Comment: yeah, i found the same way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea (but i've never heard of such a problem): could you please try to reference your css-file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="circle.css" />
```

instead of

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import "circle.css";</style>
```

**EDIT:** are the other styling-rules applied correctly? if so, please just ignore my idea... this is for "the whole stylesheet isn't loaded" - you havn't given exact information about that.

Comment: yeah everything else works fine, so this is not the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought, but shouldn't:

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import "circle.css";</style>
```

be, instead:

```
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("circle.css");</style>
```

Of course, this wouldn't (or at least *shouldn't*) explain why the stylesheet isn't being loaded locally; and if some styles other than the `border-radius` ones are being loaded/applied then this answer isn't applicable anyway.