# IE Focus with Local HTML file

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, focus

I'm having a problem with the `:focus` attribute being recognized within my HTML file saved on my local drive. I've entered the HTML and CSS in [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/raphnguyen/7Btj3/) and the `:focus` attribute works just fine as seen in this image [link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/434dv.jpg):

[image]

Basically, what I am trying to show in the image is that I am within the **Attorney Name** text field, so that is where the `:focus` attribute should be applied, which is successfully shown by a blue border around the text field. What I am also trying to show here is that there is a light blue border around the **Jail Address** button that seems to be IE's default `:focus` attribute.

When opening the HTML file saved on my local drive, the `:focus` attribute that I want to apply to the **Attorney Name** field is lost, as shown in this image [link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vI40.jpg):

[image]

Instead, the **Attorney Name** field is highlighted with the default IE `:focus` attribute. Can anyone help troubleshoot why my `:focus` is seen correctly in jsFiddle, but not on my local HTML file and how I might fix this issue? I am testing this on IE8 and IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the CSS defined in a separate file? Is that CSS file being loaded when the HTML is loaded from the local hard drive?

Comment: Yes, the CSS is a separate file (seen in the CSS portion of the jsFiddle I linked) and is loaded in the HTML page by the line `<link rel="stylesheet" Href="Slate.css" Type="text/css">`.

Comment: Which versions of IE? Oh, I see that now. Just a second, let me look at this.

Comment: Is this relevent? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692601/css3-border-radius-property-doesnt-work-in-localhost

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so because I'm not using the border-radius syntax. It also wouldn't explain why it displays properly within my browser on jsFiddle, but not when I open my local HTML file.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: The first answer at the link discusses IE compatibility modes, that is, the browser sometimes behaves as if it were an older version. In IE, I believe the focus selector is not supported until IE9, so IE7 or IE8 compatibility modes would lose the effect.

Comment: You're right! I turned on compatibility mode on the jsFiddle page and the focus went away. What's the proper way to focus for an IE version < 9?

Comment: You can use javascript to emulate the focus selector. This page might point you in the right direction: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fixing-focus-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll review that page.